# Why Does getTextSize() Change with Orientation?

Tags: android, fonts, orientation, scale

I have a small Android activity with a couple of TextViews.  The font size changes dramatically when I rotate between landscape and portrait.

The XML for one view looks like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/question"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/small_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small_margin"
    android:text="@+string/question"
    android:textSize="@dimen/medium_text_size" />
```

The medium_text_size value is defined by default in dimens.xml.  There are different dimens.xml files for different screen sizes, but NOT for -port or -land.  My device (a Samsung Note 3) reports normal screen size in both orientation, and the value in the corresponding dimens.xml is:

```
<dimen name="medium_text_size">50sp</dimen>
```

The line I added in onCreate for debugging seems simple enough too:

```
questionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
Log.d(TAG, "Raw incoming size: " + questionText.getTextSize());
```

When I rotate to portrait mode the value logged is 72.  Going to landscape, 150 is logged.  As you would expect, the text looks about twice as big.  I know that the getTextSize() return won't be the same as the value in dimens.xml, because the units are different, but I don't understand why orientation makes a difference.

There are some things I want to do with font size, but I want to understand this first.

Comment: Do you have different `dimens` for width or height, for example `w720dp`?

Comment: No, my only dimens.xml versions are in values, values-normal, values-large, and values-xlarge.  The values are 50sp, 50sp, 70sp, and 100sp respectively, which I assume are defaults since I didn't put them there.